# Conditional formatting based on a value in a separate table (related by reference)

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements

I have a worksheet (A) which details numerous references and details. In a separate sheet I have costing data (B). I do not want to show the costing data on worksheet A, so I want to set conditional formatting to display cost of the reference in comparison to another value. I want to do this by matching the reference on worksheet B and comparing it to a separate (always the same) cell in A.

How can I refer to the correct cell in worksheet B based on the reference in worksheet A, and compare it to another cell (always the same) in worksheet A in the conditional formatting rules?

For example:

Worksheet A outcome:

[image]

Worksheet B example:

[image]

Is this possible?

So far I have rules for selecting the correct value in the second sheet but I'm not sure how to automate that reference, and not sure how to automate this for the full column.

[Reference to worksheet B in conditional formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKsl1.png)

[Rule set applying to one cell.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvp9d.png) I understand that I can apply the ruleset to the full column, but not sure how to do this where I am referring to the second sheet using the correct reference.

Thanks in advance for any support.

Comment: Yes, it is possible! You should write similar formulas as you use on a sheet, having precedents from other sheets. Are you able to manually create such conditional formatting rules? Do you expect us to look at the attached pictures and do the job for you? What you tried by your own?

Answer (score 0):

If you want 4 different colors--I'm kind of guessing you mean red for >22, yellow for 18-22, green for <18, and no color for out-of-stock--then I think the key to realize is, you need 4 different rules over the same set of cells, one for each color.

Let's do the **red** one first.

1. Select C7:C10 on Worksheet A, and in the Home ribbon, click Conditional Formatting > New Rule...
2. Click "Use a formula to determine which cells to format".
3. Click "Format..." and pick whatever red color you want.
4. In the "Format values where this formula is true:" box, type a formula that will return TRUE whenever the value in A2 is > 22, such as: **=XLOOKUP($C7, 'Worksheet B'!$A$2:$A$5, 'Worksheet B'!$C$2:$C$5, FALSE) > $A$2**.
5. Click OK. Any Stock #s for any References whose cost is > 22 will now be red.

Of course, assuming what's in the pics is just an example & that your real data has more rows, then you will need to adjust the references & sheet names in the XLOOKUP formula to whatever they really are.

(I would also really recommend using a Table with Structured References for all the References / Costs, as this will enable you to add or remove References and change the number of rows of data, without having to re-adjust the conditional formatting formulas every single time you do so.)

Once you get the first color in place, the rest are a lot easier. For the **yellow** rule, you just copy the red rule you already made & adjust it slightly:

1. Making sure you still have C7:C10 selected, in the Home ribbon, click Conditional Formatting > Manage Rules...
2. Highlight the red rule, and click "Duplicate Rule".
3. Click the *last* copy of the rule, and click "Edit Rule".
4. Click "Format..." and pick whatever yellow color you want.
5. Tweak the XLOOKUP formula, so that now the very last bit says **> $A$3** instead of > $A$2. Hit OK, then OK again.

You want the yellow rule to come *after* the red one, because the rules get applied in the order that they appear. If you screw the order up though, don't worry too much, bc you can always use the up & down arrow buttons in the Conditional Formatting > Manage Rules... dialog to shuffle the order around.

For the **green** rule: just do the same thing you did for the yellow rule, but **> $A$4** this time, etc.

Last, but not least, if you wanted another rule for "out-of-stock, regardless of cost = no color": well, with the concepts here, you can definitely figure that one out now.